# Which tag or code invokes AngularJS for very first time

Tags: angularjs

Which tag or code invokes AngularJS for very first time. Or what is the entry point of AngularJS.

Let’s take the below example.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <h1>Angular application</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

ng-app specify it is an angular block. This means AngularJS is already running in the document that is why it is able to identify the directive.

Comment: when you use ng-app , it invokes AngularJs for the first time

Comment: But how my document know ng-app is a angular directive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <script src="angular.js">
```

angular.js script which registers a callback that will be executed by the browser when the containing HTML page is fully downloaded. When the callback is executed, Angular looks for the ngApp directive. If Angular finds the directive, it will bootstrap the application with the root of the application DOM being the element on which the ngApp directive was defined.

Answer (score 0):

[It's the](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) `ng-app` but you can bootrap it yourselves as well , then you have the control to initialize

```
 angular.bootstrap(document, ['demo']);
```

I think you need to look in to how angular works , [here are the basic concepts](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts)